# PyAudio no sound

Tags: python, audio

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 and am trying to figure out why PyAudio doesn't output any sound.

- `speaker-test` outputs pink noise to the headphone jack.
- `aplay sound.wav` also works
- `python3 play_wave.py sound.wav` hangs and doesn't output any sound.

`play_wave.py` is an example/test program included with the pyaudio package.

PyAudio was installed with `apt-get install python3-pyaudio`. I should mention that this is all being tested in docker, so as not to contaminate or break the host.

EDIT: Here is the play_wave.py source code (taken from [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/))

```py
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

CHUNK = 1024

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Plays a wave file.\n\nUsage: %s filename.wav" % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(-1)

wf = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')

# instantiate PyAudio (1)
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# open stream (2)
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output=True)

# read data
data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

# play stream (3)
while len(data) > 0:
    stream.write(data)
    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

# stop stream (4)
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

# close PyAudio (5)
p.terminate()
```

Comment: Post your play_wave.py code.

Comment: @CoderMike source code added